# Sql Server 2008 R2 Web setup throws application error when starting FixSqlRegistryKey_x86.exe

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-7-x64

I have Windows 7 64bit. I had Sql Server 2008 R2 Express installed. I unistalled it and then I tried to install Sql Server 2008 R2 Web. Unfortunatelly on the Setup Support Rules page for 'Consistency validation for SQL Server registry keys' I got 'Failed'. I spent half of a day trying to solve it, but then I assumed that there must be realy something wrong with registry keys and it will be faster just to reinstall Windows.

After formatting the disk and reinstalling Windows 7, rebooting dozen of times I installed all Windows upadtes as well. I also did install some programs like Skype, Thundirbird etc. which has no influence on Sql Server setup.

And then I tried again to install Sql Server 2008 R2 Web. And again an error. A bit different one. Now when the setup is on the Setup Support Rules page I get an error message box with the title **"FixSqlRegistryKey_x86 - Application Error"** and content: **The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.** 'Consistency validation for SQL Server registry keys' gets 'Failed' status as well.

My team mate has exactly the same machine as mine. He had no problem with installation (he didnt even need to reinstall Windows).

I run the setup as administrator, from a local folder. I even tried to use the setup files copied from my team mate, for a case if my copy is corrupted. In the setup options I have chosen the 'x64' version.

Any ideas what can be the reason of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Someone suggested to me that Web edition should not be installed on Win 7 (just on Windows Server). So perhaps installing a different version would work. My team mate perhaps succeeded acidentially - due to having sql server installed already in express edition... but it is just a guess.
Before I tried to install another edition of SqlServer, I downloaded 2008 Express version and I started the install. From the temporary folder created by the express edition I copied FixSqlRegistryKey_x86.exe file and I had overwritten the problematic file in the Web setup with this file. 
I started the setup again. It passed the verification this time. But has crashed on a later point - setup unpacks the installation files to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2008R2 and runs from it. So I needed to again overwrite the problematic file in this location. Now the installation succeeded.